# How to write xpath expression to find dead code

Tags: java, xpath, xsd, pmd

```
public class IdentifyProblemsInCode {
    public void howToDoInJava_method3() {
        System.out.println("how to do");
        if (true) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("in java");
    }
}
```

### THIS IS XML FOR ABOVE JAVA CODE:

```
<Block BeginColumn="41" BeginLine="4" EndColumn="5" EndLine="10" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="false" containsComment="false">
                            <BlockStatement Allocation="false" BeginColumn="9" BeginLine="5" EndColumn="40" EndLine="5" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true">
                                <Statement BeginColumn="9" BeginLine="5" EndColumn="40" EndLine="5" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true">
                                    <StatementExpression BeginColumn="9" BeginLine="5" EndColumn="39" EndLine="5" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true">
                                        <PrimaryExpression BeginColumn="9" BeginLine="5" EndColumn="39" EndLine="5" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true">
                                            <PrimaryPrefix BeginColumn="9" BeginLine="5" EndColumn="26" EndLine="5" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true" SuperModifier="false" ThisModifier="false">
                                                <Name BeginColumn="9" BeginLine="5" EndColumn="26" EndLine="5" FindBoundary="false" Image="System.out.println" SingleLine="true"/>
                                            </PrimaryPrefix>
                                            <PrimarySuffix ArgumentCount="1" Arguments="true" ArrayDereference="false" BeginColumn="27" BeginLine="5" EndColumn="39" EndLine="5" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true">
                                                <Arguments ArgumentCount="1" BeginColumn="27" BeginLine="5" EndColumn="39" EndLine="5" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true">
                                                    <ArgumentList BeginColumn="28" BeginLine="5" EndColumn="38" EndLine="5" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true">
                                                        <Expression BeginColumn="28" BeginLine="5" EndColumn="38" EndLine="5" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true">
                                                            <PrimaryExpression BeginColumn="28" BeginLine="5" EndColumn="38" EndLine="5" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true">
                                                                <PrimaryPrefix BeginColumn="28" BeginLine="5" EndColumn="38" EndLine="5" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true" SuperModifier="false" ThisModifier="false">
                                                                    <Literal BeginColumn="28" BeginLine="5" CharLiteral="false" EndColumn="38" EndLine="5" FindBoundary="false" FloatLiteral="false" Image="&quot;how to do&quot;" IntLiteral="false" SingleCharacterStringLiteral="false" SingleLine="true" StringLiteral="true"/>
                                                                </PrimaryPrefix>
                                                            </PrimaryExpression>
                                                        </Expression>
                                                    </ArgumentList>
                                                </Arguments>
                                            </PrimarySuffix>
                                        </PrimaryExpression>
                                    </StatementExpression>
                                </Statement>
                            </BlockStatement>
                            <BlockStatement Allocation="false" BeginColumn="9" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="9" EndLine="8" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="false">
                                <Statement BeginColumn="9" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="9" EndLine="8" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="false">
                                    <IfStatement BeginColumn="9" BeginLine="6" Else="false" EndColumn="9" EndLine="8" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="false">
                                        <Expression BeginColumn="13" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="16" EndLine="6" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true">
                                            <PrimaryExpression BeginColumn="13" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="16" EndLine="6" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true">
                                                <PrimaryPrefix BeginColumn="13" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="16" EndLine="6" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true" SuperModifier="false" ThisModifier="false">
                                                    <Literal BeginColumn="13" BeginLine="6" CharLiteral="false" EndColumn="16" EndLine="6" FindBoundary="false" FloatLiteral="false" Image="" IntLiteral="false" SingleCharacterStringLiteral="false" SingleLine="true" StringLiteral="false">
                                                        <BooleanLiteral BeginColumn="13" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="16" EndLine="6" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true" True="true"/>
                                                    </Literal>
                                                </PrimaryPrefix>
                                            </PrimaryExpression>
                                        </Expression>
                                        <Statement BeginColumn="19" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="9" EndLine="8" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="false">
                                            <Block BeginColumn="19" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="9" EndLine="8" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="false" containsComment="false">
                                                <BlockStatement Allocation="false" BeginColumn="13" BeginLine="7" EndColumn="19" EndLine="7" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true">
                                                    <Statement BeginColumn="13" BeginLine="7" EndColumn="19" EndLine="7" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true">
                                                        <ReturnStatement BeginColumn="13" BeginLine="7" EndColumn="19" EndLine="7" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true"/>
                                                    </Statement>
                                                </BlockStatement>
                                            </Block>
                                        </Statement>
                                    </IfStatement>
                                </Statement>
                            </BlockStatement>
                            <BlockStatement Allocation="false" BeginColumn="9" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="38" EndLine="9" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true">
                                <Statement BeginColumn="9" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="38" EndLine="9" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true">
                                    <StatementExpression BeginColumn="9" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="37" EndLine="9" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true">
                                        <PrimaryExpression BeginColumn="9" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="37" EndLine="9" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true">
                                            <PrimaryPrefix BeginColumn="9" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="26" EndLine="9" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true" SuperModifier="false" ThisModifier="false">
                                                <Name BeginColumn="9" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="26" EndLine="9" FindBoundary="false" Image="System.out.println" SingleLine="true"/>
                                            </PrimaryPrefix>
                                            <PrimarySuffix ArgumentCount="1" Arguments="true" ArrayDereference="false" BeginColumn="27" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="37" EndLine="9" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true">
                                                <Arguments ArgumentCount="1" BeginColumn="27" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="37" EndLine="9" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true">
                                                    <ArgumentList BeginColumn="28" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="36" EndLine="9" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true">
                                                        <Expression BeginColumn="28" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="36" EndLine="9" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true">
                                                            <PrimaryExpression BeginColumn="28" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="36" EndLine="9" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true">
                                                                <PrimaryPrefix BeginColumn="28" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="36" EndLine="9" FindBoundary="false" Image="" SingleLine="true" SuperModifier="false" ThisModifier="false">
                                                                    <Literal BeginColumn="28" BeginLine="9" CharLiteral="false" EndColumn="36" EndLine="9" FindBoundary="false" FloatLiteral="false" Image="&quot;in java&quot;" IntLiteral="false" SingleCharacterStringLiteral="false" SingleLine="true" StringLiteral="true"/>
                                                                </PrimaryPrefix>
                                                            </PrimaryExpression>
                                                        </Expression>
                                                    </ArgumentList>
                                                </Arguments>
                                            </PrimarySuffix>
                                        </PrimaryExpression>
                                    </StatementExpression>
                                </Statement>
                            </BlockStatement>
                        </Block>
```

Xpath expression :

//MethodDeclaration[count(ResultType)=1]/Block[(.//BlockStatement/Statement/IfStatement/Expression /PrimaryExpression /PrimaryPrefix /Literal /BooleanLiteral/@True )='true' and 
  (.//BlockStatement/Statement/IfStatement/Statement/Block/BlockStatement/Statement/ReturnStatement/@SingleLine )='true']/BlockStatement[last()]

How to write `xpath` expression to find dead code 
    in above code  `System.out.println("in java");` this line is dead code how can i find this block by using `xpath` expression

Comment: it doesn't even compile as it is an unreachable statement

Comment: Yes Nicolas.Sorry for last post Now i have add compile code this code showing dead code for  System.out.println("in java"); in eclipse.How can i find dead code by using xpath expression

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Actually it does compile.  This is by design;  `if (true)` and `if (false)` are permitted, mostly intended for testing and debugging, similar to C preprocessor `#if` blocks.

Answer (score 3):

**XPath is for selecting XML.**   It is completely the wrong tool to use to parse Java or any other programming language.  Further, dead code determination requires a reachability calculation, typically considered to be semantic analysis, not just a syntactic parse.  You're not even close to being able to do this in XPath.

---

**Update:** You've now posted an [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) from PDM in XML.  That's better than having XPath go against raw Java code, but it's still insufficient for full reachability analysis.  What you need from PDM is a [control flow graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_graph), and that doesn't appear to be a feature of PDM.

Comment: I Have added PMD plugin into eclipse IDE but PMD don't have rule to find dead code in java. All PMD rules are written in xpath.

Comment: Show the PMD report in XML that includes dead code or reachability information, then we'll show you the XPath expression to access it.

Comment: PMD (https://pmd.github.io/) allows custom rules written in XPath. It has a proper schema to do so,so it is not "completely the wrong tool".

Comment: @LittleSanti: I didn't say that PMD was completely the wrong tool; I said XPath was.  If PMD can do reachability and expose the results as XML, then, sure, XPath can play a part.  However, if PMD *only* exposes an abstract syntax tree, it's still a ways away from supporting semantic analysis necessary to identify dead code.

Comment: @kjhughes Yes, PMD exposes an AST as XML, and so, it allows to create rules based on XPath (Yet for determining reachability it is necessary semantics, that's right). But using XPath to perform static code analysis was not the OP author's idea; it was PMD's.

Comment: @LittleSanti: I understand, but it was OP's idea to write his entire question, including its title, asking about XPath without mentioning PDM except in a tag, which is easily overlooked.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: @kjhughes And now your answer is much better.